# How to conditionally reset state count with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

After the user submits my form, the `handleSubmit` function runs and counts the number of `li` elements with class names containing "show" in my `div` showing all search results. It adds these counts all up with `setStoreCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)` and I update my `FAQ {searchCount}` UI showing the number of search results with

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSearchCount(storeCount) // collect all storeCount
}, [storeCount])
```

The problem: Say that the first search gets 5 results.

Then the UI would show `FAQ 5`. If you search the same thing again, you still get 5 results and would expect the UI to still show `FAQ 5` but because the `storeCount` cannot reset to `0` it shows `FAQ 10` (5 + 5) and then `FAQ 15` (5 + 5 + 5) and so on.

Because my useEffect conditionally runs whenever `storeCount` changes, I cannot reset it to 0 because then I would always show `FAQ 0`.

How do I show the number of search results while refreshing the count on every search in the code below?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

import ContentsWrap from '../../components/contents-wrap'
import FrequentList from './tabs/frequent'
import EstimateList from './tabs/estimate'
import ReturnList from './tabs/return'
import EtcList from './tabs/etc'
import SubsidiaryList from './tabs/subsidiary'
import ServiceList from './tabs/service'
import InList from './tabs/in'
import OutList from './tabs/out'

import styles from './index.module.scss'

export default function FAQ () {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState('frequent')
  const [storeText, setStoreText] = useState('') // stores searchbar text as user types
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('') // sends searchbar text to List component props on form submit
  const [storeCount, setStoreCount] = useState(0) // stores count of each li element className that includes 'show'
  const [searchCount, setSearchCount] = useState(0) // shows search count in UI
  const searchContainer = useRef(null)
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setSearchText(storeText)
    setTab('all')
    setTimeout(() => {
      // gets all <ul> children of <div class = "faq-list-wrap">
      for (let i = 0; i < searchContainer.current.children.length; i++) {
      // gets all <li> children of each <ul>
        for (let j = 0; j < searchContainer.current.children[i].children.length; j++) {
        // checks if each li class name has 'show'
          if (searchContainer.current.children[i].children[j].className.includes('show')) {
            console.log('count added')
            setStoreCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100) // setTimeOut needed to target searchContainer after search and not before
  }
  const handleChange = newId => {
    setTab(newId)
    setStoreText('') // clear input value on tab click
    setSearchText('') // show all search items on tab click
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchCount(storeCount) // collect all storeCount
  }, [storeCount])
  return (
    <ContentsWrap>
      <div className="content-wrap content-width">
        {/* <!-- S: faq-wrap --> */}
        <div className="faq-wrap">
          <div className="faq-title-wrap"><h2 className="title">FAQ {searchCount}</h2></div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search"
              className={styles.searchBox}
              value={storeText}
              onChange={e => {
                setStoreText(e.target.value)
              }}
            />
          </form>

          {/* <!-- S: faq-list-wrap --> */}
          <div className="faq-list-wrap" ref={searchContainer} >
            {tab === 'all' && (
              <>
                <FrequentList searchText={searchText} />
                <EstimateList searchText={searchText} />
                <ReturnList searchText={searchText} />
                <EtcList searchText={searchText} />
                <SubsidiaryList searchText={searchText} />
                <ServiceList searchText={searchText} />
                <InList searchText={searchText} />
                <OutList searchText={searchText} />
              </>
            )}
            {tab === 'frequent' && (
              <FrequentList searchText={searchText}/>
            )}
            {tab === 'estimate' && (
              <EstimateList searchText={searchText}/>
            )}
            {tab === 'return' && (
              <ReturnList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
            {tab === 'subsidiary' && (
              <SubsidiaryList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
            {tab === 'service' && (
              <ServiceList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
            {tab === 'in' && (
              <InList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
            {tab === 'out' && (
              <OutList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
            {tab === 'etc' && (
              <EtcList searchText={searchText} />
            )}
          </div>
          {/* <!-- E: faq-list-wrap --> */}
        </div>
        {/* <!-- E: faq-wrap --> */}
      </div>
    </ContentsWrap>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in your `setStoreCount` logic.

In this line in your `for` loop:

```
if (searchContainer.current.children[i].children[j].className.includes('show')) {
    console.log('count added')
    setStoreCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
}
```

It adds the 1 to the `prevCount` meaning if the `prevCount` is 5 (which is the number of results on the first search, it adds 1 to that and so on.

What you can do is reset the `storeCount` before you add the number of elements found. like so:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      setStoreCount(0)
      // gets all <ul> children of <div class = "faq-list-wrap">
      for (let i = 0; i < searchContainer.current.children.length; i++) {
      // gets all <li> children of each <ul>
        for (let j = 0; j < searchContainer.current.children[i].children.length; j++) {
        // checks if each li class name has 'show'
          if (searchContainer.current.children[i].children[j].className.includes('show')) {
            console.log('count added')
            setStoreCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100) // setTimeOut needed to target searchContainer after search and not before
```

But this might make it like, it show `FAQ 0` then the rest of the count after it loops. So I suggest count it first before you set the count, like so.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      let count = 0
      // gets all <ul> children of <div class = "faq-list-wrap">
      for (let i = 0; i < searchContainer.current.children.length; i++) {
      // gets all <li> children of each <ul>
        for (let j = 0; j < searchContainer.current.children[i].children.length; j++) {
        // checks if each li class name has 'show'
          if (searchContainer.current.children[i].children[j].className.includes('show')) {
            console.log('count added')
            count++
          }
        }
      }
      setStoreCount(count)
    }, 100) // setTimeOut needed to target searchContainer after search and not before
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is just incrementing the storeCount perpetually. You should start a counter at zero at the start of the loop the loop and then assign the final value of the counter into your storeCount using setStoreCount.